# junction tables / many to many relationships

Tags: sql, ssms, relational-database, sql-server-2019, junction-table

I am using sql server to create a database and I have many to many relationships and I am wondering if it is a good idea to connect all of them in one junction table or I must create a junction for only two tables.

I have 5 tables that are many to many and I have referenced them only with one junction table.

I am not sure if I will not be doing something that is not allowed by using one junction table for all the 5 tables. I am wondering also if I will be able to query the tables connected to that junction table.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow editor now has a feature that allows you to use tables. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support). It would be much easier to help you if you provide table structures here

Answer (score 0):

You need one junction table per relationship